# Redirect route by route values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the default route in global.asax defined

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

I need to achieve this.

`/somecontroller/edit/1` - when the id is a number then let it go
`/somecontroller/edit/xxxx` - when the id is a string then redirect it to    `/somecontroller/xxxx`

and only when the action is called edit.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve. Why do you need to redirect a request to `somecontroller/edit/xxxx`? Do you need to invoke a different `Edit` method in your Controller where the id is a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `RegisterRoutes` method is url translated to name and value of controller, action and other parameters.
You can write your own map route logic - first line which is satisfied will be proceeded.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

// empty url is mapping to Home/Index
routes.MapRoute(null, "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

// accepts "Whatever/Edit/number", where Whatever is controller name (ie Home/Edit/123)
routes.MapRoute(null,
      // first is controller name, then text "edit" and then parameter named id
      "{controller}/edit/{id}", 
      // we have to set action manually - it isn't set in url - {action} not set
      new { action = "edit"},  
      new { id = @"\d+" }      // id can be only from digits
    );


// action name is AFTER edit (ie Home/Edit/MyActionMethod)
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/edit/{action}");

// default action is index -> /Home will map to Home/Index
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}", new{action="Index"}); 

// accepts controller/action (Home/Index or Home/Edit)
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");                 

// controller_name/action_name/whatever, where whatever is action method's id parameter (could be string)
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}/{id}");
```

Comment: Added more explanation. It accepts re-route only for "edit" too.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can't handle it only by routes. You need to check it inside `Edit` action and redirect to the `Index` action in case of string value, otherwise handle edit action.

**routing constraint**

```
public class IsIntegerConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    #region IRouteConstraint Members

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        int result;

        return int.TryParse(values[parameterName].ToString(), out result);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**routes**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
            new { id = new IsIntegerConstraint() }
        );
```

Comment: I was thinking maybe I can do it in some custom IRouteConstraint derived class ?

Comment: Probably yes. I've added some sample, but I didn't have a change to check it.

Comment: hmm when it is a number I return true and the execution process stops.

Comment: Check these posts:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/12/15/redirect-routes-and-other-fun-with-routing-and-lambdas.aspx

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/02/redirecting-routes-to-maintain-persistent-urls.aspx

Comment: I have to return false :-) But anyway this dosn't work for me,because when I use Response.Redirect a second request is made and the client side is waiting only for the first one. It's an ajax request.